# node js won't let me use proxies

Tags: node.js, proxy, nightmare, node-request

I'm trying to use the request-module to scrape websites and get the response-HTML. To prevent getting blocked by the target sites I need to use some proxies. But for some reason I can not accomplish to use request with a proxy.

I've also tried many different proxies and none of them will do the job.

My code:

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

var servers = [
    'http://173.249.48.240:8080',
    'http://85.214.250.48:3128'

]
var options = {
    'url': 'http://www.google.de',
    'proxy': servers[1]
};


request(options, (err,res,body) => {
    console.log(res);
    console.log(body);
    console.log(err);
    try {
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        console.log($('#ipv4').html());
    } catch(err) {
        //do nothing
    }

})
```

I've tried many different proxies and have also used nightmare before but everytime I try to connect with a Proxy I get the following exception:

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 85.214.250.48:3128
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1046:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1182:14)
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '85.214.250.48',
  port: 3128 }
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you have network access to the proxies from the machine you are running the node.js app from? Does the proxy need any sort of authentication to be used?

Comment: None of the proxies needs any kind of authentication. Most of the ips came from [https://hidemy.name/en/proxy-list/](https://hidemy.name/en/proxy-list/)

Comment: You may want to check if those proxies are actually functional as I can't connect to them

Comment: Ok, that sounds quite bad. Do you have any reliable sources for a proxy that works?